# HTML & CSS - navigation bar won't float horizontally using float left

Tags: html, css, web

Trying to make a navigation bar horizontal with the logo on the left but the text won't move. Anybody got any idea why not?

https://jsfiddle.net/herxforn/1/

CSS

```
body {
    width 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;

}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You haven't used `float:left` in your CSS!!!

Comment: Use `float: left` for logo and `float: right` on `nav` and replace `width` width `max-width: 80%` or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with flexboxes:

```css
body {
  width 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav img{
  max-width: 50px;
  max-heigth: 50px;
}
nav ul {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}

nav ul li {
  flex: 1;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>



<title>URBANFITNESSNI</title>
<body>
  <nav>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" alt="logo" height="50px" width="50px">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/about">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/membership">Membership Details</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/facilities">Facilities</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

added demo

```css
body {
  width 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li,
nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>



<title>URBANFITNESSNI</title>

<body>


  <img src="C:\Users\Ross\Documents\UrbanFitnessNi\assets\logo.png" alt="logo">


  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/about">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/membership">Membership Details</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/facilities">Facilities</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Delete

```
nav ul li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;

}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and change for this:

```
nav ul li,
nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is how it looks now which is the same as it was before: http://puu.sh/qhwJj/af5a41105b.png

Comment: added demo. check it

Answer (score 0):

look at this.

https://jsfiddle.net/herxforn/5/

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>



<title>URBANFITNESSNI</title>

<body>


  <img src="C:\Users\Ross\Documents\UrbanFitnessNi\assets\logo.png" alt="logo">


 
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/about">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/membership">Membership Details</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/facilities">Facilities</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class to your image and float it to the left as well.

css

```
body {
  width 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li,
nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>



<title>URBANFITNESSNI</title>

<body>


  <img src="C:\Users\Ross\Documents\UrbanFitnessNi\assets\logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">


  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/about">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/membership">Membership Details</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/facilities">Facilities</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> a navigation bar horizontal with the logo on the left

Put the logo in the nav an float the image and the `ul`

```css
body {
  width 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: black;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
nav img {
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/40/40" alt="logo">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/about">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/membership">Membership Details</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/facilities">Facilities</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/faq">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```